# What is the Maximum Current an Arduino can Supply?

Tags: current, input

I was wondering how much my Arduino I/O pin can output when it is set at **Output** and is at **High**.

I am using an **Arduino Uno R3**.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: @brhans Alright, Gonna move it there

Comment: @brhans but it seems to have an answer already. So i think im just gonna keep it here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much current can I draw from the Arduino's pins?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-much-current-can-i-draw-from-the-arduinos-pins)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

40.0mA.

The Arduino UNO Digital IO pins are connected directly to the IO pins on the ATMEGA328P processor.

From page 299 of the [data sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3p_GkrpnKAhWEQyYKHVBiCJUQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2Fimages%2Fatmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEfBUXFG85G6huz6IpUbv0LQqhvGQ&sig2=9zwktRebt6GXlhApMf7Zzg) for that processor...

[image]

Note that there is also a total current limit for all output pins combined, and that the voltage starts to drop as the current goes up.

Comment: You should probably note that it's never a good idea to go anywhere near the "Absolute Maximum Ratings". Perhaps include the notice that's referred to by the asterisk on that page in the datasheet.